# Neural network model training accuracy remaining at 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

My code is

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 5)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

And my output is

```
    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 3920)              0

 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               501888

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258

=================================================================
Total params: 502,146
Trainable params: 502,146
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
219/219 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f8750280790>
```

Why do all training accuracy converge to 0? My dataset is

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
(7000, 28, 28, 5)
(3000, 28, 28, 5)
print(train_labels.shape)
(7000, 1)
```

And I tried other models, including con2D model or logistic regression model, but accuracy is always 0. That's really weird. Does the issue come from my dataset? My train_labels only contains 1s and (-1)s.

Comment: Labels should be 0 and 1, not -1.

Comment: Does the current answer have any merit? Or is it completely bogus? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score -2):

Try adjusting the learning rates or the label is not suitable, because the loss function value return is [NaN](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NaN#Noun).

1. First you need to consider the label as an int or float format.
2. Look into the sample dataset label distributions and vary, have 1 or 2 (1, 2) as your networks required.
3. If *from_logits* is enabled, you need to compare the output of the networks with the label and logits shape return. Example (1, 2) with 2 number of the output layer.
4. The Flatten layer is working in old versions. You should use the Input layer that is suitable with a dataset or you rename it as 'flatten_input' as your input layer name.
5. The rest is about data and networks suitable tasks, contrast input, and target. Try to add more layers or image alignment to create a contrast of data, but if the data is not an image, but a screen or shared information in resizes scales, networks should match to data.

Sample: Working with the Flatten layer, you need to map of the input name to it.

```
dataset = {
    "flatten_input" :[],
    "label" : []
}
dataset["flatten_input"].append(tf.constant(image, shape=(1, 28, 28, 1)))
dataset["label"].append(tf.constant(label, shape=(1, 1, 1, 64)))
```

Sample: Simply working on the [MNIST dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSets
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
ds = ds.shuffle(1024).batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
assert isinstance(ds, tf.data.Dataset)

for example in ds.take(1):
    image, label = example["image"], example["label"]

ls_image = []
ls_label = []
for i in range(label.shape[0]):
    ls_image.append(tf.constant(image[i], shape=(1, 28, 28, 1)).numpy())
    ### should reflects the label in number format ###
    ls_label.append(tf.constant(0, shape=(1, 1, 1, 1)).numpy())

image = tf.constant( ls_image, shape=(64, 1, 784, 1) )
label = tf.constant( ls_label, shape=(64, 1, 1, 1) )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( image, label ))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(784, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
    ])
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, epochs=50 )
```

Output: Numbers happen

```
Epoch 1/50
51/64 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.0123e-09 - accuracy: 1.0000
```